# Problem with kicad installation { : Depends: libglew1.13 (>= 1.12.0) which is a virtual package and ... }

Tags: linux-mint

My system is like this:

[image]

```
System:    Host: notebook Kernel: 5.2.0-0.bpo.3-amd64 x86_64 bits: 64 compiler: gcc v: 8.3.0 
           Desktop: Cinnamon 4.2.4 wm: muffin dm: LightDM Distro: LMDE 3 Cindy 
           base: Debian 9.3 stretch 
Machine:   Type: Laptop System: LENOVO product: 80TV v: Lenovo ideapad 310-15IKB serial: <filter> 
           Chassis: type: 10 v: Lenovo ideapad 310-15IKB serial: <filter> 
           Mobo: LENOVO model: Torronto 5C2 v: NO DPK serial: <filter> UEFI [Legacy]: LENOVO 
           v: 3JCN26WW date: 03/07/2017 
Battery:   ID-1: BAT0 charge: 10.4 Wh condition: 10.4/30.0 Wh (35%) volts: 8.4/7.4 
           model: SMP L15M2PB3 serial: <filter> status: Full 
CPU:       Topology: Dual Core model: Intel Core i7-7500U bits: 64 type: MT MCP arch: Kaby Lake 
           rev: 9 L1 cache: 128 KiB L2 cache: 4096 KiB L3 cache: 4096 KiB 
           flags: lm nx pae sse sse2 sse3 sse4_1 sse4_2 ssse3 vmx bogomips: 23232 
           Speed: 700 MHz min/max: 400/3500 MHz Core speeds (MHz): 1: 700 2: 700 3: 700 4: 700 
Graphics:  Device-1: Intel vendor: Lenovo driver: i915 v: kernel bus ID: 00:02.0 
           chip ID: 8086:5916 
           Device-2: NVIDIA GM108M [GeForce 920MX] vendor: Lenovo driver: N/A bus ID: 03:00.0 
           chip ID: 10de:134f 
           Display: server: X.Org 1.19.2 driver: modesetting unloaded: fbdev,vesa 
           resolution: 1920x1080~60Hz 
           OpenGL: renderer: N/A v: N/A direct render: N/A 
Audio:     Device-1: Intel vendor: Lenovo driver: snd_hda_intel v: kernel bus ID: 00:1f.3 
           chip ID: 8086:9d71 
           Sound Server: ALSA v: k5.2.0-0.bpo.3-amd64 
Network:   Device-1: Realtek RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet vendor: Lenovo 
           driver: N/A port: 5000 bus ID: 01:00.0 chip ID: 10ec:8168 
           Device-2: Realtek RTL8821AE 802.11ac PCIe Wireless Network Adapter vendor: Lenovo 
           driver: rtl8821ae v: kernel port: 4000 bus ID: 02:00.0 chip ID: 10ec:8821 
           IF: wlp2s0 state: up mac: <filter> 
Drives:    Local Storage: total: 1.82 TiB used: 1.21 TiB (66.6%) 
           ID-1: /dev/sda vendor: Seagate model: ST2000LM003 HN-M201RAD size: 1.82 TiB 
           speed: 6.0 Gb/s serial: <filter> temp: 33 C 
Partition: ID-1: / size: 196.17 GiB used: 38.73 GiB (19.7%) fs: ext4 dev: /dev/sda7 
           ID-2: /home size: 196.17 GiB used: 190.71 GiB (97.2%) fs: ext4 dev: /dev/sda3 
Sensors:   System Temperatures: cpu: 43.0 C mobo: N/A 
           Fan Speeds (RPM): N/A 
Repos:     Active apt repos in: /etc/apt/sources.list 
           1: deb http: //ppa.launchpad.net/commendsarnex/winedri3/ubuntu artful main
           2: deb-src http: //ppa.launchpad.net/commendsarnex/winedri3/ubuntu artful main
           3: deb http: //ftp.de.debian.org/debian/ jessie main contrib non-free
           4: deb https: //deb.torproject.org/torproject.org stretch main
           5: deb-src https: //deb.torproject.org/torproject.org stretch main
           6: deb http: //http.kali.org/kali sana main non-free contrib
           7: deb http: //security.kali.org/kali-security/ sana/updates main contrib non-free
           8: deb http: //ppa.launchpad.net/linrunner/tlp/ubuntu xenial main
           9: deb http: //ppa.launchpad.net/ppa-name/ubuntu lucid main
           10: deb http: //ppa.launchpad.net/js-reynaud/kicad-5.1/ubuntu xenial main
           11: deb-src http: //ppa.launchpad.net/js-reynaud/kicad-5.1/ubuntu xenial main
           12: deb http: //ppa.launchpad.net/ppa-name/ubuntu lucid main
           13: deb http: //ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/y-ppa-manager/ubuntu lucid main
           14: deb http: //ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/y-ppa-manager/ubuntu lucid main
           15: deb http: //ppa.launchpad.net/wine/wine-builds/ubuntu lucid main
           Active apt repos in: /etc/apt/sources.list.d/additional-repositories.list 
           1: deb http: //ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/java/ubuntu trusty main
           2: deb http: //deb.debian.org/debian stretch main
           3: deb-src http: //deb.debian.org/debian stretch main
           4: deb-src http: //deb.debian.org/debian stretch-updates main
           5: deb http: //deb.debian.org/debian stretch-updates main
           6: deb-src http: //security.kali.org/kali-security/ sana/updates main contrib non-free
           7: deb-src http: //http.kali.org/kali sana main non-free contrib
           8: deb http: //http.kali.org/kali kali main contrib non-free
           9: deb http: //security.kali.org/kali-security kali/updates main contrib non-free
           10: deb http: //repository.spotify.com stable non-free
           11: deb https: //dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu/ bionic main
           12: deb https: //dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu/ stretch main
           Active apt repos in: /etc/apt/sources.list.d/buster-backports.list 
           1: deb http: //deb.debian.org/debian buster-backports main contrib non-free
           Active apt repos in: /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list 
           1: deb [arch=amd64] http: //dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/ stable main
           Active apt repos in: /etc/apt/sources.list.d/jessie-backports.list 
           1: deb [check-valid-until=no] http: //archive.debian.org/debian jessie-backports main
           Active apt repos in: /etc/apt/sources.list.d/jessie.list 
           1: deb [check-valid-until=no] http: //cdn-fastly.deb.debian.org/debian jessie main
           Active apt repos in: /etc/apt/sources.list.d/lutris.list 
           1: deb http: //download.opensuse.org/repositories/home:/strycore/xUbuntu_18.04/ ./
           Active apt repos in: /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mongodb-org-4.0.list 
           1: deb http: //repo.mongodb.org/apt/debian jessie/mongodb-org/4.0 main
           Active apt repos in: /etc/apt/sources.list.d/official-package-repositories.list 
           1: deb http: //mirror.rise.ph/linuxmint cindy main upstream import backport
           2: deb http: //debian.inf.tu-dresden.de/debian/ stretch main contrib non-free
           3: deb http: //debian.inf.tu-dresden.de/debian/ stretch-updates main contrib non-free
           4: deb http: //security.debian.org/ stretch/updates main contrib non-free
           5: deb http: //www.deb-multimedia.org stretch main non-free
           Active apt repos in: /etc/apt/sources.list.d/official-source-repositories.list 
           1: deb-src http: //mirror.rise.ph/linuxmint cindy main upstream import backport
           2: deb-src http: //debian.inf.tu-dresden.de/debian/ stretch main contrib non-free
           3: deb-src http: //debian.inf.tu-dresden.de/debian/ stretch-updates main contrib non-free
           4: deb-src http: //security.debian.org/ stretch/updates main contrib non-free
           5: deb-src http: //www.deb-multimedia.org stretch main non-free
           Active apt repos in: /etc/apt/sources.list.d/opera-stable.list 
           1: deb https: //deb.opera.com/opera-stable/opera stable non-free #Opera Browser (final releases)
           Active apt repos in: /etc/apt/sources.list.d/pritunl.list 
           1: deb http: //repo.pritunl.com/stable/apt jessie main
           No active apt repos in: /etc/apt/sources.list.d/terry_guo-gcc-arm-embedded-saucy.list 
           Active apt repos in: /etc/apt/sources.list.d/tor.list 
           1: deb-src https: //deb.torproject.org/torproject.org bionic main
           Active apt repos in: /etc/apt/sources.list.d/vscode.list 
           1: deb [arch=amd64] http: //packages.microsoft.com/repos/vscode stable main
           Active apt repos in: /etc/apt/sources.list.d/webupd8team-java-wheezy.list 
           1: deb http: //ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/java/ubuntu wheezy main
           2: deb-src http: //ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/java/ubuntu wheezy main
Info:      Processes: 306 Uptime: 1d 19h 38m Memory: 11.69 GiB used: 7.54 GiB (64.5%) 
           Init: systemd v: 232 runlevel: 5 Compilers: gcc: 6.3.0 alt: 6 
           Client: Unknown python3.5 client inxi: 3.0.32
```

when i want to install kicad with aptitude i get this output:

```
 sudo aptitude install kicad
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  kicad{b} libngspice-kicad{a} libssl1.0.0{a} 
The following packages are RECOMMENDED but will NOT be installed:
  kicad-demos kicad-doc-en kicad-libraries 
0 packages upgraded, 3 newly installed, 0 to remove and 1 not upgraded.
Need to get 25.0 MB of archives. After unpacking 109 MB will be used.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 kicad : Depends: libglew1.13 (>= 1.12.0) which is a virtual package and is not provided by any available package

The following actions will resolve these dependencies:

     Keep the following packages at their current version:
1)     kicad [Not Installed]                              



Accept this solution? [Y/n/q/?] y
No packages will be installed, upgraded, or removed.
0 packages upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 1 not upgraded.
Need to get 0 B of archives. After unpacking 0 B will be used.
W: Target Packages (main/binary-amd64/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:20 and /etc/apt/sources.list:25
W: Target Packages (main/binary-i386/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:20 and /etc/apt/sources.list:25
W: Target Packages (main/binary-all/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:20 and /etc/apt/sources.list:25
W: Target Translations (main/i18n/Translation-en_US) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:20 and /etc/apt/sources.list:25
W: Target Translations (main/i18n/Translation-en) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:20 and /etc/apt/sources.list:25
W: Target DEP-11 (main/dep11/Components-amd64.yml) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:20 and /etc/apt/sources.list:25
W: Target DEP-11 (main/dep11/Components-all.yml) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:20 and /etc/apt/sources.list:25
W: Target DEP-11-icons (main/dep11/icons-64x64.tar) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:20 and /etc/apt/sources.list:25
W: Target Contents-deb (main/Contents-amd64) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:20 and /etc/apt/sources.list:25
W: Target Contents-deb (main/Contents-i386) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:20 and /etc/apt/sources.list:25
W: Target Contents-deb (main/Contents-all) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:20 and /etc/apt/sources.list:25
```

So how could i install it?

Comment: I don't have any answer, but your Linux Mint system has **quite** a collection of repos! Ubuntu, Kali, and *several* Debians!

Comment: yes i am newbie in Linux Mint and this happened by searching through internet and doing the different solution, but now i have replaced Mint with Ubuntu and i would consider your warning. ( dose this situation is harmful and create some bugs and ...?)